# how to use group by in xmltable oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, group-by, xmltable

When I use `group by` in XML table it's throwing error:

> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than one requested number of rows

I tried LISTAGG() function as solution but it did not resolve the problem.

My SQL

```
   SELECT xmlelement("logs", xmlagg(xmlelement("log", xmlforest(v1.column_1 as "id", v1.column_2 as "name")))).getclobval()
   INTO   v_output 
   FROM   xmltable( '/logs/log' passing xmltype(in_xml) columns id number path 
  'id' ) x 
 JOIN   view v1 
 ON     v1.id= x.id;
```

Input xml

```
declare
  in_xml clob := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <logs>
        <log>
            <id>123456</id>
        </log>
        <log>
            <id>456898</id>
        </log>
    </logs>';
  v_output clob;

begin

   select xmlelement("logs", xmlagg(xmlelement("log", xmlforest(v1.column_1 as "id", v1.column_2 as "name")))).getclobval()
  into v_output
  from xmltable(
    '/logs/log'
    passing xmltype(in_xml)
    columns id number path 'id'
  ) x
  join view v1 on v1.id = x.id
 GROUP BY  v1.id;

  dbms_output.put_line (v_output);

end;
```

Any solution is most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your first query is fine as originally written, however, in your second code block you've introduced the `group by` clause which may be making your query return multiple records, yet you are trying to select them into a single output variable.

You either need to limit your query to a single ID, or change v_output to a collection of clob values and use bulk operations:

```
declare
  in_xml clob := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <logs>
        <log>
            <id>123456</id>
        </log>
        <log>
            <id>456898</id>
        </log>
    </logs>';
  type t_clob is table of clob;
  v_output t_clob;

begin

   select xmlelement("logs", xmlagg(xmlelement("log", xmlforest(v1.column_1 as "id", v1.column_2 as "name")))).getclobval()
  bulk collect into v_output
  from xmltable(
    '/logs/log'
    passing xmltype(in_xml)
    columns id number path 'id'
  ) x
  join view v1 on v1.id = x.id
 GROUP BY  v1.id
 fetch first 10 rows only;

 for iter in v_output.first .. v_output.last loop
   dbms_output.put_line (v_output);
 end loop;   
end;
```

Some caution should be exercised with the above code as it can, without the fetch limit, potentially exhaust available memory if a large number of rows are selected into v_output. As currently written only the first 10 records will be retrieved and written out.

Comment: HI Senetial still in output duplicate record exist